# Solving this composite function

Tags: calculus, functions, absolute-value

Solve
$f(x)=(|x+3|+x)/(x+2)>1$

My solution:

$|x+3|>2$

my answer- $(-∞,-5)\cup(-1,∞)$ except $-2.$

I do not know what mistake I'm doing,because my answer is wrong, please cope with me as it is my first question.

Comment: (|x+3|+x)/(x+2)>1 is only equivalent to |x+3|>2 if $x+2>0$.

Comment: thanks for edit suggestions, please can you explain in detail?

Comment: If you multiply both sides of an inequality by a number, the sign stays the same if the number is positive and the sign switches if the number is negative. So if $x+2>0$, then $\frac{|x+3|+x}{x+2}>1$ is equivalent to $|x+3|+x>x+2$, i.e. $|x+3|>2$, and if $x+2<0$, then $\frac{|x+3|+x}{x+2}>1$ is equivalent to $|x+3|+x<x+2$, i.e. $|x+3|<2$. We know $x+2\neq 0$, because if $x+2=0$, then $\frac{|x+3|+x}{x+2}$ is not a real number / is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{|x+3|+x}{2+x} - 1 >0  \Longleftrightarrow \frac{|x+3|-2}{2+x}>0$$

Case $x+3\geq0$: Solve for the solutions of $0<\frac{x+3-2}{2+x}=\frac{x+1}{x+2}$

Case $x+3<0$: Solve for the solutions of $0<\frac{-(x+3)-2}{2+x}=\frac{-x-5}{2+x}$